# When do I use Multiply and Add

Tags: neural-network, keras, convolutional-neural-network

I want to know the effect of `Add` and `Multiply` in keras by functionality. The dumb way of thinking is that they are meant to add and multiply keras tensors. I want to know when are they to be used. For example, look at the code below from [here](https://github.com/titu1994/keras-squeeze-excite-network/blob/master/se.py). Why use `Multiply` in `spatial_squeeze_excite_block` and why use `Add` in `channel_spatial_squeeze_excite`? Can we switch `Add` and `Multiply` in these functions? Why not?

```
def spatial_squeeze_excite_block(input):
    ''' Create a spatial squeeze-excite block
    Args:
        input: input tensor
    Returns: a keras tensor
    References
    -   [Concurrent Spatial and Channel Squeeze & Excitation in Fully Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.02579)
    '''

    se = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', use_bias=False,
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(input)

    x = Multiply([input, se])
    return x


def channel_spatial_squeeze_excite(input, ratio=16):
    ''' Create a spatial squeeze-excite block
    Args:
        input: input tensor
        filters: number of output filters
    Returns: a keras tensor
    References
    -   [Squeeze and Excitation Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.01507)
    -   [Concurrent Spatial and Channel Squeeze & Excitation in Fully Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.02579)
    '''

    cse = squeeze_excite_block(input, ratio)
    sse = spatial_squeeze_excite_block(input)

    x = Add([cse, sse])
    return x
```

Comment: About the multply operation : in the spatial_squeeze_excite_block, you compute a feature map that could be interpreted as a mask (values between 0 and 1 because of sigmoid activation), multiplying the mask with the initial tensor will effectively mask some values from the initial tensor. (very much like in a attention mechanism even though there is no attention here)

Comment: In general I'd say the Add operation between layers outputs is meant to gather the information of the 2 layers (you could concatenate but here you don't increase the dimension )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are defined that way. Have a look a the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.01507) cited in the docstring. The sse is defined in eq. 3, and the scSE is defined in the text in 2.3.